# iOS How to auto layout HeaderReferenceSize

Tags: ios, xib, collectionview

I have an section headerView in my collectionView . and I load headerView from `xib` . my problem is , I must set the headerView's height by hardcode :

```
 layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: self.view.width, height: 50)
```

so I cant adaptation height to different screen models.

I set all the frame by the screen width scale ,so when I load it from `xib` ,it will have an default value. so I don't want right an hard value to the `headerReferenceSize`.

it's there any way to let `headerReferenceSize` automatically fit ?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?